# Blocking after Facebook deactivation

Tags: facebook

I have just deactivated my Facebook account. Can someone still block me? Am I still showing up on their friends list for them to do so?

Answer (score 6):

I have had a couple friends deactivate their accounts temporarily.  In each instance, I was not able to see them in my friends list anymore, and their comments to my posts disappeared as well.

If you deactivate your account, you will not appear in anyone's friends list, and no one will be able to find you.  They have to be able to find you in order to block you, so no one will be able to block you while your account is deactivated.

Comment: In my experience, deactivated accounts still show up in my friends list. However, they have no portrait or hover popups, and clicking them sends me back to the Facebook home page. This is different from permanently-deleted accounts.

Comment: @Phong That is interesting.  I know my 2 friends didn't permanently delete their accounts, because when they came back, they didn't have to re-friend me and all their old posts/comments came back as well.  Perhaps Facebook has changed whether they appear in your friends list.

Comment: Yeah, I caveated it with "in my experience" simply because Facebook changes things like this all the time, and also performs isolated testing on a subset of users on occasion. I last checked just a few weeks ago, but I wouldn't be surprised if the behavior was modified since then. At the moment I don't believe I have any deactivated friends to check with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they still can block/ignore you according to this tutorial

http://newsmyviews.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-to-block-ignore-deactivated-person-facebook-profile-account-2015.html

Comment: Always consider essential contents of the link in your answer.

Comment: Ok, I shall be using essential material from link.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that if this link stops working, this answer is _worthless_. Answers on Stack Exchange should be self-contained. By all means link to the source to give credit, but a person shouldn't need to follow yet another link to get the information they seek.

Answer (score 0):

you can still see the deactivated friend on your list if you are using the browser which shows an empty profile pic. However, if you are using the FB app, deactivated friends wont appear on your friends listing. Note: you can still 'unfriend' a deactivated account using the browser sign in NOT through the app but there is no option of blocking the person. you need to wait until they are active to block them.